# Fixing Java Properties

Tags: java

Java Properties docs strongly discourages the use of put and putAll methods. I just had a look at the source code of Properties class, I am a bit surprised to see extended Hashtable parameterized type is set to Object rather than String. Is there an other reason apart from backward compatibility? Also Can Properties class not override put and putAll methods with an extra precondition (I know it's a violation of LKP but extending Hashtable was a bad choice anyway), roughly, like :

```
if(p1 instanceof String && p2 instanceof String) {
          return super.put(p1, p2);         
}else {
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid argument type");
}
```

Thanks,

Abidi

Comment: `Properties` is an old class predating generics by the better part of a decade, and the design decision to make it inherit the now deprecated-ish `Hashtable` hasn't exactly aged well. I usually prefer using `ResourceBundle` to parse .properties files instead, and populate a `Map<String, String>` explicitly when I need to update values at runtime.

Comment: The reason why they couldn't make the type parameters String is because it would break an application that actually uses Properties to store non-String objects. While this would very much be an erroneous use of the class, the JDK policy is to never cause old code to not compile anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree it's pretty annoying (and poorly documented in the API docs), but yes, it's for backwards compatibility.

In pre-generic java, if you call `put(key, value)` with a non-String as a value, a Properties instance would not throw an exception, (but it would return `null` from `getProperty(key)`).

If they had implemented the above amendment, the same calling code would 'fail sooner'. Hundreds of java apps & servlets around the world would probably fail to load properly, and there'd be much wailing & gnashing of teeth.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I agree it would have been better to do the test as you mentioned, but I guess the authors of the Properties class was not as smart as you :)